# Is there an 'analog' AND gate?

Tags: operational-amplifier, switches, logic-gates, comparator, buffer

I'm also looking for some component that will have two inputs: the signal (call it pin A) and a reference (pin B). The reference will either be 0V or 1V/5V, so basically on/off. If B is on, then the component will let the signal pass through. If B is off, then the component will block with signal and output 0V. Does such device exist, or can it be made using some more common components like op-amp?

thanks

Comment: An analog switch.

Comment: Half of what you describe is analog multiplexer, the original 405x series are still available today in DIP packages, https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/CD4053BE/296-2059-5-ND/67309. However signal A is restricted to the being between the supply rails.

Comment: This can also be done with a relay, which will not be limited to the supply rails, but is slow and will have contact bounce. Oh and it's big and heavy and goes click, which is not appropriate for many applications..

Comment: @uint128_t how does relay work? I don't need it to be very quick (less than one second is already very good for my application)

Comment: How about you explain what you are doing?  Then we can give you ways to accomplish that instead of guessing.

Comment: [Relay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relay). It's a mechanical switch that is actuated by an external voltage (B in your case). So if you use an [SPDT](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/switch-basics/poles-and-throws-open-and-closed) relay and ground one throw, it does what you want.

Comment: Do you really need 0 V when the switch is off? SP**S**T switches are open, i.e., the output has no defined voltage.

Comment: actually what I want to do is to make a protective switch that will open the circuit if the signal exceeds a certain value (~12-13V). I find something quite similar here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/111983/open-a-circuit-when-voltage-exceeds-a-certain-value, but I'm just wondering if there are other options and also I don't entirely understand the two MOSFETs there.

Comment: A summing op amp

Comment: all logic is made from analog parts , they just saturate beyond linear region. Even FF's are made from transmission gates

Answer (score 3):

A single analogue switch might do what you want: -

[image]

It's basically a relay in chip form but there are certain things you need to consider: -

- The chip needs a supply voltage
- When routing the signal through to either NO or NC there will be an equivalent contact resistance of several tens of ohms for some devices. Some devices are sub 1 ohm of course but exhibit "features".
- Off isolation isn't as good as a convention electromechanical relay due to capacitance between input and output "contacts". Low on-resistance types are usually worse with respect to off-isolation. This usually doesn't matter too much for audio but at hundreds of kHz this can become a problem.
- It's not a good idea to expect you can pass hundreds of mA through it although some are able to work with this sort of current.

One improvement is to use two analogue switches so that when the pass switch is "open circuit", the 2nd switch shorts the output to ground thus mitigating the effects of the off-isolation capacitance.

You can use a JFET too: -

[image]

There are some problems with this circuit also - it doesn't quite fully isolate because it relies on the on-resistance of the JFET being low enough to reduce the signal at the output to minimal levels and this might still leave an unacceptably significant level.

Or there is this type of optically controlled switch from [Omron](https://www.omron.com/ecb/products/search/?cat=1&did=2&prd=mosfet&lang=en): -

[image]

They do a version with 1 ohm on resistance and about a pico-farad off-capacitance.

It all boils down to you deciding what performance you want.